# ASMX Web service not returning to jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, asmx

SOLVED: YOU CANNOT RETURN A DICTIONARY FROM AN AJAX WEB SERVICE, USE A LIST!

I am trying to call a ASP.NET Web service from jQuery.

The Web service runs, but the results are not returned to the javascript. Any idea why? I think I could be missing something in web.config or..?

jQuery:

```
function GetAccountTypes() {
        var ddl = $("#ListBoxType");
        clearSelect(ddl.attr("id"));
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService.asmx/GetAccountTypes",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
                var accTypes = response.d;
                var options = ddl.attr("options");
                $.each(accTypes, function (index, accType) {
                    options[options.length] = new Option(accType.Value, accType.Key); 
                });
            },
            failure: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
    }
```

Web Service:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

public WebService()
{
}

[WebMethod]
public Dictionary<int, string> GetAccountTypes() {
    Dictionary<int, string> types = new ATDB().GetAccountTypes();
    return types;
}

}
```

web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Setting a break point in the js function and in the web service method shows that the method runs but it never reaches 'success' or 'failure'.

Comment: The Ajax programmer's best friend: Fiddler. Use it to determine what the response of the web server actually is.  That'll tell you a lot about what might be wrong.  http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: your function GetAccountTypes() wait for a json format...  are you sure that the service return the dictionary in json format??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found out that you cannot return a Dictionary from a Web Service as it implements IDoctionary and is not serializable. Solution: Return a list of a simple custom object.

Answer (score 0):

your function GetAccountTypes() wait for a json format... are you sure that the service return the dictionary in json format?? I think... no.

web services are SOAP based web services, you might consider migrating your web services to WCF, in which you'll have much control over the output format that you need.

check out this material

http://blog.clauskonrad.net/2010/11/how-to-expose-json-endpoint-from-wcf.html